# How to speed up scanning all txt files in sdcards?

Tags: android, file, sd-card

I used recursive function to scan all the paths under /mnt/sdcard and find out all the file ends with .txt, but I found that it is very slow if I using it on my real android phone.
Is there anything like Buffered Input Stream to speed up the scanning process?

```
                    private txtFileFilter txtff = new txtFileFilter();

                    private void scanAllTxtFiles(File location, ArrayList<String> list) {

                        File[] files = location.listFiles(txtff);
                        if (files != null) {
                            for (File f : files) {
                                if (f.isDirectory()) {
                                    scanAllTxtFiles(f, list);
                                } else if (f.isFile()) {
                                    list.add(f.getAbsolutePath().substring(
                                            externalPathLength));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

                private class txtFileFilter implements FileFilter {

                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (pathname.isFile()
                                && pathname.getName().length() >= 4
                                && pathname.getName()
                                        .substring(pathname.getName().length() - 4)
                                        .equals(".txt")) {
                            return true;
                        } else if (pathname.isDirectory()) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }

                }
```

Comment: can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: You should show us your recursive function, perhaps someone could find a way to improve its performance

Comment: @user2011482 Looks a bit truncated to me.

Comment: @piokuc I call it and start with "/mnt/sdcard"